# Specifying a Header within a list of similar files

Tags: r

I am aware that my question is straightforward and bound to be a duplicate.

I have a great amount of files (which have all the same formats-in terms of header, and row names) which I open using a file.list:

```
library(readxl) 
file.list <- list.files(pattern=".xlsx")
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

My ultimate goal is to merge every file in this list. However, I still need to assign a specific header.

I thought about doing something like this, as the header I want is placed on the 2nd row of each file:

```
df.list2 <- lapply(df.list,df.list[-2,])
```

Or specifying the header name such as:

```
df.list2 <- lapply(df.list,read_excel(header=c("list of column entries representing my header")
```

None of that is working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if your headers are in 2nd row of the files themselves, you can set the arguments `col_names = TRUE` and `skip = 1` for `read_excel`. Your second call to `lapply` will need to be a function, which isn't the case in your second or third code block.

Comment: How can I create such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would read the files and create a list of `data.frame`s:

```
lapply(df.list, function(file_path){
  read_excel(file_path, skip = 1, col_names = TRUE)
})
```